# Array object restructure

Tags: javascript

I have Javascript object like this:

```
var value=[ RowDataPacket {options: 'card_img_url',options_value: 'https://ttest.com/logo.png' },RowDataPacket {options: 'card_img_url',    options_value: 'https://ttest.com/logo2.png' },RowDataPacket {options: 'card_description', options_value: 'card 1 desc ' },RowDataPacket {    options: 'card_description',options_value: 'card 2 desc' },RowDataPacket {
options: 'card_footer',options_value: 'card 1 footer' },RowDataPacket {
options: 'card_footer', options_value: 'card 2 footer' }];

var shaym = [];             
for(var i=0; i<value.length; i++){ 
var itemoptions = value[i].options;
var itemoptionsval = value[i].options_value;             
var temp = {};
temp[itemoptions] = itemoptionsval;
shaym.push(temp);
```

}

```
console.log(shaym);
```

It shows -

```
[{ card_img_url: 'https://ttest.com/logo.png' },{ card_img_url: 'https://ttest.com/logo2.png' },{ card_description: 'card 1 desc ' },{ card_description: 'card 2 desc' },{ card_footer: 'card 1 footer' },{ card_footer: 'card 2 footer' } ]
```

Form the above code I want this type objects:
[{ card_img_url: 'https://ttest.com/logo.png', card_description: 'card 1 desc ', card_footer: 'card 1 footer'},{ card_img_url: 'https://ttest.com/logo2.png', card_description: 'card 2 desc ', card_footer: 'card 2 footer'}]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I want to restructure the test objects through for loop like below.

Comment: You have to show your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: var value=[ RowDataPacket {
    node_input_option_id: 9,
    node_id: 4,
    options: 'card_img_url',
    options_value: 'https://ttest.com/logo.png'' },
  RowDataPacket {
    node_input_option_id: 10,
    node_id: 4,
    options: 'card_img_url',
    options_value: 'https://ttest.com/logo2.png'' } ];

var shaym = [];             
for(var i=0; i<value.length; i++){ 
    var itemoptions = value[i].options;
    var itemoptionsval = value[i].options_value;             
    var temp = {};
    temp[itemoptions] = itemoptionsval;
    shaym.push(temp); 
     
}
console.log(shaym);

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Move it into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the key of the object is the same as the key of the previous object. If same take the next index for the result array, otherwise zero. Then assign the object to the result set.

```js
var data = [{ card_img_url: 'https://ttest.com/logo.png' }, { card_img_url: 'https://ttest.com/logo2.png' }, { card_description: 'card 1 desc ' }, { card_description: 'card 2 desc' }, { card_footer: 'card 1 footer' }, { card_footer: 'card 2 footer' }],
    result = data.reduce(function (last, i) {
        return function (r, a) {
            var k = Object.keys(a)[0];
            i = k === last ? i + 1 : 0;
            r[i] = r[i] || {};
            r[i][k] = a[k];
            last = k;
            return r;
        };
    }(), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, It works. You have save my lot of time.

Comment: hi nina, thanks for the previous one, but if I add ojects like : var data = [{ node_input_option_id: 10 },{ card_img_url: 'https://ttest.com/logo.png' }, { node_input_option_id: 11 },{ card_img_url: 'https://ttest.com/logo2.png' }, { node_input_option_id: 12 },{ card_description: 'card 1 desc ' }, { node_input_option_id: 13 },{ card_description: 'card 2 desc' }, { node_input_option_id: 14 },{ card_footer: 'card 1 footer' }, { node_input_option_id: 15 },{ card_footer: 'card 2 footer' }] , It can not display result as the previous one.

Comment: it's a problem with the properties. the above relies on connected same keys, whereas the actual object looks like a random sorted array. what is the building rule of grouping for it?